# Oracle OBIEE Dashboard tab blank

Tags: oracle, tabs, dashboard, obiee

We have a user in our organization who has a recurring, but sporadic and rare, problem of dashboard tabs in Oracle OBIEE 12.2.1.4.0 loading with no data. The tab looks like it loads successfully, but no data displays, either tables or charts. Other tabs on the same dashboard load correctly, data displays, etc. It is not always the same tab, sometimes it is multiple tabs, most times it loads just fine. We are unable to recreate the issue on our end, and his computer has even been replaced, but the issue still happens, though again very sporadically.

He is the only user who seems to have this issue. Our vendor who supplies us with their OBIEE based analytic system has given us some settings tips but not been able to resolve it completely for us. He is currently using Chrome, but reports that he has also used Internet Explorer and gotten the same result.
Has anyone else had this problem?